# jquery if else statement hasClass addClass click

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm new to jQuery but I am already incredibly impressed with its power. Here's my question:

I want to

- add `class='dec'` to `#jf1` when I click it if it has `class='undec'`
- add `class='undec'` to `#jf1` when I click it if it has `class='dec'`

Here's what I have - it isn't working!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {

    $('#jf1').click(function() {

        if ('#jf1'.hasClass("undec")) {
            $('#jf1').toggleClass("undec dec");
    }
        else if ('#jf1'.hasClass("dec")) {
            $('#jf1').toggleClass("dec undec";
    }

    });

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: why you use $(document) and $(function) both together ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several syntax errors in your code, your if statement should be:

```
if ( $('#jf1').hasClass("undec") ) {
```

Also `$(function(){})` is shorthand version of `$(document).ready(function(){})`, you should not nest them. `toggleClass` removes and adds classes, so there is no need to use `if` statement here.

```
$(function() {
    $('#jf1').click(function() {
        // `this` refers to the clicked element
        $(this).toggleClass("undec dec");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response.

I agree that .toggleClass is perfect for this - but I wanted to use an if/else statement because when I click the item, I also want to .show or .hide an element based on its CSS class, based on whether or not the "filter" has class='dec' or class='undec'

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/YS5F5/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#jf1').click(function () {
        alert("hello");
        $('#jf1').toggleClass("undec");
        $('#jf1').toggleClass("dec");

    });
});
```

dont need the function again after the jQuery(document).ready portion